# How to selector a code of some of the same code in WP Web Scraper?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I use [WP Web Scraper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/) to take the title from the following link :
http://lpse.acehtenggarakab.go.id/eproc/lelang/view/1316330

The title is: PENGAWASAN/SUPERVISI KEGIATAN FISIK TAHUN 2016

The title is inside a `<td>` html tag with an attribute `class="horizLine"` (It is located on the second line (`<tr>` html tag) of this html `<table>` that contains 68 lines).

My WP Web Scraper shorthcode is:

```
[wpws url="http://lpse.dephub.go.id/eproc/lelang/view/33737114" selector=".horizLine"]
```

But It doesn't work.

My Question:
How can I target this title in the `selector` attribute of my shortcode, while others ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add some more elements in your shortcode `selector` attribute, because the displayed html source is:

```
<tr>
    <td width="150" class="TitleLeft">Kode Lelang</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="horizLine"><b>1316330</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="TitleLeft">Nama Lelang </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="horizLine">
        <b>
            <strong>PENGAWASAN/SUPERVISI KEGIATAN FISIK TAHUN 2016</strong>
        </b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> …
```

Here is the solution to target the title is `selector="tr:nth-child(2) td.horizLine b strong"`:

```
[wpws url="http://lpse.dephub.go.id/eproc/lelang/view/33737114" selector="tr:nth-child(2) td.horizLine b strong"]
```

With `:nth-child(2)` I am targeting the 2nd `<tr>` html element.